# How to change buffer coding system in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have a file in emacs with the buffer coding system set to "no conversion", showing an equals sign ("=") in the mode-line.

I don't know how to change this coding system.

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use `C-x RET r`, which invokes function `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` for this.

Comment: I didn't have C-x RET r bound to that function. But the function itself worked fine. Thanks. I will accept the answer as soon as the system lets me.

Comment: @Dervin: Strange, it's not my custom binding, rather something standard.  You can use `C-h w` to find if that function is bound to any key in your case.